# I couldn't send email with subject by AWS SES

Tags: python, email, aws-lambda, mime, amazon-ses

I would like to create a program that extracts data from a web site, visualizes it as a graph, and sends an email with it attached.
I was able to send it without a subject, but I really want to add a subject.
I thought there might be a problem with msg = MIMEMultipart().

```py
# Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

    # msg = MIMEMultipart()  ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←Here!
    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=REGION)
```

However, if I comment out that, I got this error:

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 193, in lambda_handler
    r = send_email(SRC_MAIL, DST_MAIL, title, message, "/tmp/img.png")
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 138, in send_email
    'Data':msg.as_string(),
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/message.py", line 158, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 195, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 222, in _write_headers
    self.write(self.policy.fold(h, v))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/_policybase.py", line 326, in fold
    return self._fold(name, value, sanitize=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/email/_policybase.py", line 369, in _fold
    parts.append(h.encode(linesep=self.linesep, maxlinelen=maxlinelen))END
```

```py
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import boto3
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import locale


SRC_MAIL = "aaa@a.co.jp"
DST_MAIL = ["aaa@a.co.jp"]
REGION = "ap-northeast-1"


def make_email_html():
    result = "<h1>this is h1</h1>"
    return result


def send_email(source, to, subject, body, img_absolute_path):
    # The character encoding for the email.
    CHARSET = "utf-8"
    # Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    # Add subject, from and to lines.
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = source
    msg['To'] = to
    
    # Create a multipart/alternative child container.
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    # Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
    # necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.

    s = make_email_html()
    htmlpart = MIMEText(s.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)
 
    # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

    # msg = MIMEMultipart()
    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=REGION)
    
    att = MIMEApplication(open(img_absolute_path, 'rb').read())
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.path.basename(img_absolute_path))
    
    # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
    # parent container.
    msg.attach(msg_body)
 
    # Add the attachment to the parent container.
    msg.attach(att)
    
    response = client.send_raw_email(
        Source=source,
        Destinations=to,
        RawMessage={
            'Data':msg.as_string(),
        }
    )
    
    return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    title = 'this is title'
    message = json.dumps(event, indent=4)
    r = send_email(SRC_MAIL, DST_MAIL, title, message, "/tmp/img.png")
    
    return r
```